# JQuery Collapsable DIV losing functionality after re-creating HTML code

Tags: jquery

I have a collapsable DIV which at the click of a button I re-create the HTML to create a different collapsible DIV. However, the second DIV I create is not collapsable.

You can see this problem here http://jsfiddle.net/Shinksy/SfcTk/7/

Click on the search button and you will see a collapsable DIV, click on the 'Message' button and this should also then create a collapsible DIV. However, it is not collapsible anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById()` in your code when you have jQuery at your disposal?

Comment: Cause I have not got a clue what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Call both functions on click of search. It will work-
JS-

```
//Set global variables
var newData = "";
var statusReport = "X";
var innerHtml = "";
var defaultHTML = "";


//Handle Search
$("#idoc_search").click(function() {
    requestProcessedSearch();
});

function changePage() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#results_page", {})
}

function requestProcessedSearch() {

    document.getElementById('resultTable').innerHTML = "";

    defineNewStatusDiv();

    defineNewMessageDiv();//Call function here

    changePage();

}

function defineNewStatusDiv() {

    innerHtml = null;
    defaultHTML = null;        

    innerHtml = document.getElementById('resultTable').innerHTML;

    defaultHTML = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" id="status">' + '<h3>Status</h3>' + '<table id="chart' + '51' + '" class="imagetable">' + '<tr>' + '<th>IDoc</th>' + '<th>Message Type</th>';

    alert(defaultHTML);

    innerHtml = innerHtml + defaultHTML;

    document.getElementById('resultTable').innerHTML = null;

    document.getElementById('resultTable').innerHTML = innerHtml;

}

function defineNewMessageDiv() {

    innerHtml = null;
    defaultHTML = null;

    innerHtml = document.getElementById('resultTable').innerHTML;

    defaultHTML = '<div class = "ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">' + '<h3>Message</h3>' + '<table id="chart' + 'MATMAS' + '" class="imagetable">' + '<tr>' + '<th>IDoc</th>' + '<th>Status</th>';

    innerHtml = innerHtml + defaultHTML;

    document.getElementById('resultTable').innerHTML = null;

    document.getElementById('resultTable').innerHTML = innerHtml;

}
```

Here's the fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/SfcTk/11/

PS- You can use Jquery **appendTo** without making DOM as NULL.

Comment: I do not want to call both functions though, I want the function defineNewMessageDiv(); to be called when I click the search button

Comment: You are calling a function inside function, you are calling defineStatusDiv() function but you did't call function to make message div and i.e. what you missed- function requestProcessedSearch() {

    document.getElementById('resultTable').innerHTML = "";

    defineNewStatusDiv();

    defineNewMessageDiv();//Call function here

    changePage();

}

Comment: I have amended the link to reflect what I want to happen. When you click search, it will run the defineNewStatusDiv(); method. When you then click the message button it will then run the defineNewMessageDiv() method to show new collapsible DIV. However, it is losing its functionality.

Comment: @MartinShinks It never had the functionality, the `jQuery` functionality is initialized o, `changePage`

Comment: @jb10210- Yeah! It never had the functionality. DOM is not used properly. And Jquery is always better than traditional Javascript. Good attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfcTk/15/)

I 'updated' your code to use `jQuery` as it should be used.

The reason your second collapsible `div` wasn't collapsible is because, the `html` code you generated isn't being initialized by `jQuery`. For the first one this is done on the `changePage` call (I guess, not that familiar with `jQuery-mobile`), the second one just replaced the `innerHtml`with some html containing some useless `css` classes if not initialized!

What I did was initializing the two collapsible `div`s, each in a separate results-div-container before the actual `changePage` and when clicking the message button, I hide the first and show the second (which was hidden at initialization), easy!

Watch the code and see how easy it is using `jQuery` to manipulate the `DOM` compared to your initial post!

Comment: Hi jb1020, I like the way you have simplified the code. Yes you are correct, I am a beginner with this JQuery Mobile stuff.

Comment: @MartinShinks If you now want to update the table with data or something on click, just do that functionality before the `show` in the `click` handler. PS. If this is correct, please mark so! :)